# Can a case statement be used before executing a merge statement?

Tags: sql-server, merge

Experts, hello.  Can a case statement be used to execute, or not execute, a merge statement?  I am new to the merge function.  In my situation, I am passing the values to these parameters into my stored procedure as follows:

```
 @1ID int = NULL
,@1Value float = NULL
,@2ID int = NULL
,@2Value float = NULL
,@3ID int = NULL
,@3Value float = NULL
,@4ID int = NULL
,@4Value float = NULL

AS
--1
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING
    (
        SELECT 
             @1ID
            ,@1Value

    ) AS S (
             CookSampleId
            ,ReadingValue

    ) ON (
        T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID

    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET

            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            CookSampleID
            ,ReadingValue

        ) VALUES (
             @1ID
            ,@1Value

        )
;
--2
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING
    (
        SELECT 
             @2ID
            ,@2Value

    ) AS S (
             CookSampleId
            ,ReadingValue

    ) ON (
        T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID

    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET

            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            CookSampleID
            ,ReadingValue

        ) VALUES (
             @2ID
            ,@2Value

        )
;

--3
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING
    (
        SELECT 
             @3ID
            ,@3Value

    ) AS S (
             CookSampleId
            ,ReadingValue

    ) ON (
        T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID


    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET

            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            CookSampleID
            ,ReadingValue

        ) VALUES (
             @3ID
            ,@3Value

        )
;

--4
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING
    (
        SELECT 
             @4ID
            ,@4Value

    ) AS S (
             CookSampleId
            ,ReadingValue

    ) ON (
        T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID

    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET

            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            CookSampleID
            ,ReadingValue

        ) VALUES (
             @4ID
            ,@4Value

        )
;
```

The problem I am running into is that there may be null values for some of the parameters being fed in.  This causes the stored procedure to fail ("Cannot insert the value NULL into column...").  Using this example, I may have values for @1ID/@1Value, @2ID/@2Value, and @3ID/@3Value, but not @4ID/@4Value.  So I want the merge statement that handles @4ID to not execute if @4ID is = NULL.  I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
--4
CASE IF @4ID <> NULL THEN
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING
    (
        SELECT 
             @4ID
            ,@4Value

    ) AS S (
             CookSampleId
            ,ReadingValue

    ) ON (
        T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID


    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET

            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            CookSampleID
            ,ReadingValue

        ) VALUES (
             @4ID
            ,@4Value

        )
;
```

But it appears that is cannot be done.  There is probably some better way to handle this.  I am eagerly awaiting your suggestions.  And thanks for your time!

Comment: You mean `IF @4ID IS NOT NULL MERGE`? `CASE` is part of expressions, not a statement.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear on that point.  I basically mean that if @4ID is null, then ignore it.  Only execute those merge statements where the parameter is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I would compress the entire thing into one MERGE with conditional updates/inserts.

As Jeroen points out - the ID must be unique or this may have undesirable effects.

```
MERGE FACT_CookReading AS T
    USING (SELECT @1ID AS CookSampleId, @1Value AS ReadingValue UNION
           SELECT @2ID, @2Value UNION
           SELECT @3ID, @3Value UNION
           SELECT @4ID, @4Value) AS S 
    ON T.CookSampleID = S.CookSampleID

    WHEN MATCHED AND S.CookSampleID IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE SET
            ReadingValue = S.ReadingValue

    WHEN NOT MATCHED AND S.CookSampleID IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT (CookSampleID,ReadingValue) 
        VALUES (S.CookSampleID,S.ReadingValue);
```

Comment: This is subtly different to the original if 1) the `ID` values are not unique (though, in all likelihood, they will be, or should be) and/or 2) updating or inserting a `NULL` value (not ID) should be allowed.

Comment: Quite right, I hadn't considered #1... Will fix for #2, that was an oversight.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post!  I will look over this suggestion, try it out, and post my results next week.  I should mention that in regard to the post by Jeroen above, indeed the ID is unique, and we do not want to insert a value if the value is NULL.

Comment: That was easier than I thought.  JiggsJedi's solution worked perfectly.  Again, I thank you for your help.  Now I can move on to the next conundrum. :)